# sti and form for problem with rails 3

Tags: routes, ruby-on-rails-3, form-for, sti

This is similar to   [STI and form_for problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578633/sti-and-form-for-problem) but the answer given there doesn't play nice with rails 3 and gives a deprecation warning.  However, if I try and use the new syntax, I get a very confusing result.  Here's the problem.

An event_enquiry is a kind of enquiry, and in the old syntax I would do

```
<%= form_for( :event_enquiry, @enquiry, :remote => true, :url=>{:id=>@enquiry.id,:action=>:build_provider_versions}
```

This generates the path expected 
    /event_enquiries/1/build_provider_versions
and in the log i see
    Started POST "/event_enquiries/1/build_provider_versions" for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-12-22 22:00:11 +0000

but this gives a deprecation warning

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Using form_for(:name, @resource) is deprecated. Please use form_for(@resource, :as => :name) instead.
```

BUT although the new syntax

```
<%= form_for(  @enquiry, :as => :event_enquiry,:remote => true, :url=>{:id=>@enquiry.id,:action=>:build_provider_versions}
```

appears to generate the same route, and in the log i get exactly the same message
    Started POST "/event_enquiries/1/build_provider_versions" for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-12-22 22:01:58 +0000
the route apparently does not exist!

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/event_enquiries/1/build_provider_versions"):

I've been back and forth through this and cannot see what is going on.  Does anyone have a clue what's happening?

Obviously I'm happy to drop back to the old syntax for now, but I have a nasty feeling something is broken here ... or am I just being stupid?

Answer (score 0):

just add

```
 :html => {:method => :put}
```