# Sign in inherited user after registration with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, single-table-inheritance, sti

I am using rails 3.2.14 and devise 3.2.1, and I have an "Admin" with an STI relationship with my devise "User" model.

When I register a new Admin with the form below, I get the following error:

```
undefined method `new_admin_session_path' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::RoutesProxy:0x007fa6fe068f18>
```

because I have:

```
devise_for :users, :skip => :registrations do
```

in my routes.

How can I register a new "Admin" and then sign them in as a "User"?

Please note that if I exchange "Admin" for "User" in my form_for, and remove the skip registrations from "User" in my routes, then I get the behaviour I want apart from it is a "User" not an "Admin".

I have created a stand alone application to demonstrate my problem. https://github.com/deathwishdave/devise_test

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
end
```

admin.rb

```
class Admin < User
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(Admin.new, :as => :admin, :url => registration_path(:admin)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

  <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>
```

routes.rb

```
  devise_for :users, :skip => :registrations do
      delete '/logout', :to => 'sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
      get '/login', :to => 'sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
      post '/login', :to => 'sessions#create', :as => :user_session
  end

  devise_for :admins, :skip => :sessions

  authenticated :user do
    root :to => "dashboard#index"
  end

  authenticated :admin do
    root :to => "dashboard#index"
  end

  root :to => 'welcome#index'
```

---

## Update

Requirements…

1. Four different user roles.
2. Ability to easily add additional roles in the future.
3. Single log-in/sign-in form for all roles.

Additional Information.

1. All current and future roles share the same state (have the same DB fields)
2. Every role has different relationships with other model classes.

To satisfy these requirements, I considered multiple options including STI, polymorphic associations, authorisation gems and just separate models and tables.

polymorphic associations are a poor choice because the fields between roles are the same, and it may cause difficulties with user creation. Authorisation gems such as cancan are not an option, as the roles have different relationships with other model classes. If I were to use cancan, the User model would be polluted by relationships that don’t apply to all users. Having separate models, and tables would not allow for a single point of entry for all types of user.

STI seems like a good fit because all role fields are the same, so the database will be normalised. Additional users can be added with ease.

And from a purist perspective, it makes sense. My different roles are all users, with a user being an interface or contract for all other specialties.

Comment: In your routes, you have skipped `:session` for `:admins`. Did you have this restriction in place when you got your error. (I believe yes.) You should remove this restriction and then try.

Comment: @Chandranshu - But I want the session as a "User", not an "Admin"

Comment: k, you have managed to confuse me. You want to sign up an admin and sign them in as a user? AFAIK, devise (or any authorization frameworks) for that matter will not allow this out of the box. Think about why. *(Hint: There was a recent question about it on SO.)*

Comment: I would be interested to know why you need this behaviour? I think i can help you find a better solution :), this seems pretty "hackish".

Comment: @jokklan - Thanks for your reply, I have updated the original question to answer your question. In addition to the points I raise there, I have also arrived at this point in order to support a legacy system, however I do still think it's the best solution. If there is a superior alternative, I would love to hear it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### STI vs polymorphic

Based on the requirements and information you give about the user does STI seems like fine solution, especially if there is different logic associated to each user. However polymorphic associations would work fine as well, even if each roles doesn't have any other database informations (see http://railscasts.com/episodes/394-sti-and-polymorphic-associations).

### Note on CanCan

Correct me if im wrong but CanCan seems like a good solution still, also with STI. CanCan is roled based so you can check what type of user you are authorizing and then create the rules (with relations) based on that user type/role.

### Login admin as user

To answer you actual question on how to login a admin as a user should you be able to simply override the method [`sign_up` in registration controller](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/v3.2.1/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb#L98-L102), like this:

```
class Admin::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def sign_up(resource_name, resource)
    sign_in(:user, resource)
  end
end
```

and add the following to your routes:

```
devise_for :admins, :skip => :sessions, :controllers => { :registrations => "admins/registrations" }
```

Also i find this link about STI and devise, it's a little different scenario than yours, but properly still some useful hints for you: http://adamrobbie.me/blog/2013-3-29-sti-with-rails-40-beta-and-devise

Comment: Thanks for the reply, following your instructions, I get the following error on registration. LoadError in Admin::RegistrationsController#create Expected /Users/Pingu/Rails/devise_test/app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb to define RegistrationsController

Comment: The convention in rails is to group namespaced files in folders with the same name. That means that you should move your `RegistrationsController` to `app/controllers/admin/registrations_controller.rb`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you have some really good reasons for STI, but I've always found it easier to just add another integer column to my user model that specifies a type of role. And then I deal with authorization with a tool like [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan). This way you can add as many roles as you need by just adding a new constant to your `user` model.

---

It doesn't seem so bad to have relationships that you're not always using. You can just check the `user` role before allowing a user to take any actions that would make use of the relationship. Plus, these relationships shouldn't return anything meaningful if you never make use of them. I'm not sure what your concern is.

Comment: You may also find this useful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578633/sti-and-form-for-problem

Comment: although jokklan answered my specific question, I think I might end up going with your solution for simplicity.

Comment: glad you found my answer helpful. i think it will hopefully help you avoid unnecessary headache down the line.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to write your own registration action when you want nonstandard behavior with Devise.

For example, you can put something like this in your registration controller:

```
def create
  @admin = Admin.new(user_params)

  # do some special configuration for admins
  @admin.role = 'super' 

  if @admin.save
    # sign the user into the user scope (as usual) 
    # and also sign them into the admin scope (per your special case)
    sign_in(:admin, @admin)
    sign_in(:user, @admin)
    redirect_to some_path
  else
    # show error
  end
end
```

As long as your form parameters match what devise expects (email, password, password_confirmation, etc.) it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks Nick, but this isn't a scalable solution.

Comment: It isn't scalable in what sense?

Comment: Adding additional user types.

Comment: Its not working for my case In which I am having customer and user as STI Model

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the devise is routing you to the `new_<resourcetype>_session_path` after account creation. You can alter this behavior by adding `after_sign_up_path_for` method in your `RegistrationsController`.

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  new_user_session_path
end
```

Comment: This does not work, the user is not logged in. You can see I tried it by looking at the github project I linked to. I think the problem is more fundamental.